# Difference between Land line and Fix line in telephony

Tags: differences

I'm looking for the difference between a land line and a fix line (or even fixed line) in the context of telephony.

Both seems to mean the Phone line that is not the Mobile one but I would like to know if there is any difference between them. 
If those are synonyms when use one over the other ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a technical  term-of-the-art, and regular English usage will not apply.

Comment: It's "Fixed line" and "landline". A simple google search will answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landline

Comment: I've worked around the edges of telecommunications for half a century, and "fixed line" is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the input; this could also be an answer, I'm not a native speaker, neither are the people that use that word around me (telephony company in non english speaking country).

Answer (score -1):

They are the same thing. Both terms refer to a physical phone line connecting to one or more sockets in a building (or fixed position payphone)